# Implement kerberos auth to my organization angular 7 and node.js web app

Tags: node.js, angular, active-directory, kerberos, angular7

I am a beginner to Kerberos SSO integration in Angular + Node project. I went through many of the links and forums related to it. However, not able to figure out, From where to start?

Still trying to find a way to implement the Kerberos SSO in my application.

I already read and understand the concept of Kerberos, but I can't see any examples of how to use it practically.

Below is the scenario:

I have an Angular application, I need that only registered to the Active Directory computer will be able to access the web.

I have to do the auth using Kerberos, but I don't know how to start.

Thanks for helping.